# How to handle a bunch of 0s and 1s with a microcontroller?

Tags: c, microcontroller, microchip

I'm making a program to receive a bunch of 0's and 1's with a µC and need to take any amount of bits (1 to 16) from any position.

I.E. I have 150 bits and I want to take 6 bits from the 32th bit and copy it to a char (8bits) variable; I know I can do it with strings by saving as ASCII 0's and 1's, but I have not a lot of RAM, so I need to save it as bits.

The bigger variable is a unsigned 32 bits long, but save the data is not my problem, the problem is how to access to a specific bits positions and copy that to a char(8) variable.

Comment: maybe use bitmasks?

Comment: I've never used bitmask before. Since the bigger variable is 32bits long if I need to extract the bits from 28th to 36th this should work?

Comment: 36? Where is a bit 36 in 32-bit variable?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Please re read, I have 150 bits split in several 32bits variables.

Comment: Are you familiar with boolean logic: AND and OR?  ...same principle, but done on multiple bits. For example you can use AND (&) to clear some bits --> if you AND something with 0, the result can only be zero. ex. byte tmp = byteVar & b00001111; will 'get' the bottom four bits..if any of those bits were set in 'byteVar', they will now be set in 'tmp'. You can set bits using the OR operator: if you OR something with 1, the answer can only be 1.

Comment: In combination with this you can use shift operators to set specific bits -- ex. for (int x = 0; x < 8; ++x) tmp = 1 << x; // each iteration, the 1 will  be in a different position, then use OR or AND to set/clear that specific bit.

Comment: Arduino (probably not the first..but what I'm familiar with) has a few macros defined for making this easier: cbi (clear bit) and sbi (set bit). But you really have to understand the &, |, and ~ operators. Anyway, sorry not full code, but I think you have enough to get you started...I'd start with a pc version (faster debugging?) until you're 100% comfortable with bit manipulation and moving the data around.

Comment: Are the 150 bits coming in as a stream (and thus can be serially worked upon, potentially saving a lot of memory) or do they come in as one single data block?

Comment: @dwelch You said bitmasks are evil then proceeded to recommend a solution that uses bitmasks. I'm confused, which is it? :P

Comment: @dwelch Perhaps you meant bit-fields are evil?

Comment: lol....yes I meant bit-fields...bitmasks are pure goodness..

Comment: Yes, I'm sampling a protocol similar to SPI but the problem is, after I have all those bits in several variables how to extract the bits that I want. Let's say I have 5 32 bit variables to save 150bits and I wan to get 6 bits starting from bit 28th. In this situation I need 4 bits from the firs variable and 2 from the second. So, How do that? That's the question.

Comment: Well count the bits coming in, at the required place roll N bits into your byte, although I don't understand how you can get 5 32 bit variables in 150 bits.

Comment: 32*5=160 So 10 bits are unused. Maybe you are understanding the opposite that I'm doing, I have a serial port that receives 150 bits and I store those bits in 5 32bits variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bitwise operators:

```
//bits: your bits (byte array), start: index of the first bit of the char you want
char select(char* bits, int start) {
    dec = start%8;
    return bits[start/8]>>dec + bits[start/8+1]<<dec;
}
```

The code above supposed start < (bits.size()-8)

[**EDIT**]
You can change the char* to any type you want. However you will need to change dec value to the appropriate number of bits (8*SIZE_IN_BYTES) and then apply operator | ("logical or") to get your char back

example:

```
char select(int* bits, int start) {
    nbitsint = 8*4;
    dec = start%nbitsint;
    if (dec < nbitsint-8) {
       // | 0xff creates creates a byte
        return (bits[start/nbitsint]>>((3-dec/8)*8+dec%8) | 0xff;
    }
    // Getting a byte which is astride two values is tricky
    return (bits[start/nbitsint]>>(start%8) + bits[start/nbitsint+1]<<(start%8) | 0xff;
}
```

Comment: The bigger variable that the compiler accepts is 32bits long. It's possible to create a longer bit array? I've never do that before.

Comment: The **minimum size** of a variable is a **byte** (8 bits), that's why I used a *char* (which is 1 byte). To use bigger variable (like *int32* you mentionned), you need to adapt the shift to the number of bytes needed.

Comment: Yes, but I have 150bits splitted in 5 32 bit variables, is not a single variable. So if I want 6 bits from 28th bit I will need 4 bits from the first variable and 2 from the second variable.

Comment: I assumed your variable are sorted in an array (if they are not they are sorted). If you want 8 bits from the 28th, you simply rigth shift the first variable by 27 (28th ~ 27 index) (dec variable in the code above) and left shift the second by 6, then add them and select the last byte

Comment: Sorry, I had not understood that you had meant by "byte array", now I understand.

Comment: So far I've had other tasks to be assigned to me but I think I will be able to solve by creating an array as you indicated me, thanks.